# Postion to connect LED in transistor LED circuit

Tags: transistors

Regarding a simple LED transistor circuit, with an NPN transistor if I connect an LED between emitter and ground, it does not light up. But it does if I connect between -ve and collector.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.